Calculating greeks by finite difference in MC simulation
I am calculating greeks for exotic options with finite difference in a MC simulation, overall preferring central difference to forward difference.
I compute the small changes in share price and volatility as a percentage of the original share price and volatility, say I add/deduct 0.5%-1.0% to the original value and run the simulations with this new value.
For example:
S_up = S0 * (1 + delta_S)
vola_up = sigma * (1 + delta_sigma)

where delta_S and delta_sigma are percentages of 0.5% to 1%

With this method I tend to get quite close to the greeks stated by QuantLib.
However out of curiosity I asked ChatGPT, Claude and Gemini and they all told me that this way of calculating greeks is wrong and that I should set an absolute and smaller amount rather than a percentage.
When I tried to run simulations by adding/deducting a fixed amount (much smaller than the amount that I end up adding/deducting using a percentage), the resulting greeks are way off.
My question: is the percentage method really wrong for a MC simulation?

Are you using the same random variables or creating new ones? If you’re creating new ones it’ll add noise

Thanks for your comment! I have seeded the random generator in python, they are the same.

Just ignore LLMs. See also https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/76788/54838

Thanks, so I take it that the approach of varying share price and vola by +/- 1% is ok for calculating greeks in MC.

P. Glasserman. Monte Carlo Methods in Financial Engineering, 2010 as well as M. Henrard. Sensitivity computation. OpenGamma (July 2014) are commonly referenced sources when it comes to shift sizes. It's often suggested to use something like 1% of spot: shift=spot∗1%/2
For example, the below screenshot shows what Bloomberg's DLIB pricing engine uses by default .

Vega is frequently computed with forward difference. Delta etc with central difference, as discussed in this answer.
In general, when assessing any complex pricing engine, it is helpful to price vanilla options and compare to closed form Black Scholes for pricing and Greeks.
If you bump and reprice black Scholes closed form, a small bump or large bump makes little difference (unless you reach the limits of machine precision), as shown here.
With MC, you will run into numerical issues if the bump is too small.
. https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/63663/54838 has some details and explains the distinction between Model and Market Greeks.
It's best to ignore LLMs for good, otherwise you'll think SABR stands for the initials of the models creators, of which one is Mr. SABR himself, and another one Hirakazu Hagan.
