Difference between VIX9D and IV of 7 days near the money calls on S&P500
What is the difference between VIX9D and IV of 7 days near the money calls on S&P500? (Or the VIX and 30day calls)
I was wondering if there is a thumb rule about this.
Looking at the current SPX options chain it seems to me to be about fluctuating between 2-3% but I couldn't find available historical data to show that this is true historically or in more volatile market times.

This question is similar to: implied volatility for close to expiry ATM options vs VIX. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. For short, the The VIX index is basically the discrete analog of the square root of the theoretical fair variance swap strike and the more pronounced skewness and kurtosis, the higher VIX relativ to ATM IV.

https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/75990/54838 shows the calculation in detail and compares a generic ATM 30D IV with the VIX in a chart.

Using ATM 30D call option to backout the IV (that is the expected 30D volatility) via Black-Scholes forces you to incorporate the implicit risk-neutral assumption (and others, such as normality of log returns), which may not be reflective of the real world.
The VIX uses a "model-free" non-parametric method to compute the expected 30D volatility. Therefore, there are no assumptions made when computing this measure, and may be more accurate.
